# Minecraft Windows 10 and Android Pocket Edition no longer connect

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Until just a few days ago I was able to connect either my Windows 10 PC Minecraft to my Android Minecraft, but now I get errors connecting from Android to the Windows 10 PC and in Windows 10 I don't see the Android server on my LAN.

Android gives this error when trying to connect:

[image: Unable to connect to world. Minecraft]

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app on android, it has the same issue. Oddly enough, I have an old Android tablet and that does connect, so I feel like it's something with the Android version.

Comment: Mobile and Dekstop versions are not developed in step so beware.

Comment: @PaulStelian https://www.windowscentral.com/minecraft-pocket-edition-and-windows-10-edition-are-same-thing

Comment: I must have assumed the Java edition (the Windows 10 app is a variant of Pocket Edition in a sense). And yes, even today the Java edition is still being developed and getting new versions.

Answer (score 0):

They changed it. All PE worlds no longer connect to PC/Mac worlds.